# Nothing happens when Notification with closed App clicked

Tags: swiftui, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter

When I click on the Notification when the App is closed, no prints are outputted, but I'm waiting for "app opened from PushNotification tap 2".

When the App is in background mode, everything is Ok, I see "app opened from PushNotification tap 1". Any idea what I'm missing?

Here is full example code:

```
import SwiftUI
import UserNotifications

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Request Permission") {
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { success, error in
                    if success {
                        print("Success")
                    } else if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }

            Button("Schedule Notification") {
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "Title"
                content.subtitle = "Subtitle"
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

                let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or perhaps the code doesn't work just for me?

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        return true
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("app opened from PushNotification tap 1")
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        print("app opened from PushNotification tap 2")
        completionHandler([.banner, .sound, .badge])
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like the configuration was correct. What is the scenario? Can you try it with a mock .apns file on the simulator, for example? And also try to conform `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, did it execute this?

Comment: Edited my post, added a new function to a Listener class and didReceiveRemoteNotification. Still doesn't work.
Unfortunately, I don't have a developer account, so I can't try with a mock .apns and a RemoteNotification.

Comment: Did you add the AppDelegate in SwiftUI App? If not, check here [Link](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app)

Comment: Damn. Asad, many thanks! Would you pls post this as an answer? I'll check it as right.

Comment: Now it works when the app is in the background mode, but doesn't work when it's closed. Problem is half solved.

Comment: Sure, I need some reputation points:)

Comment: @Asad: That doesn't help the site, and so it is not an efficient or durable way to gain reputation. The question will be closed and will likely be deleted in a few days, and so all reputation, both good and bad, will be lost.

Comment: Thank you. I will follow the guidelines for future questions and answers.